# How to split each words from several lines of a word file? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, file

I have a text file:

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

Instruction: Open the file and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

Desired output:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

I'm stuck here:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    lst = line.split()
    lst.append(line)
    lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: ``line.split()`` will split by spaces you might remove that.

Comment: How am i supposed split it into words then?

Comment: why does 'in' come before 'lives'?

Comment: Alphabetical order ig.

Comment: * 'He' will come before 'I' .

Comment: @RifatAbdurRahman could you please clarify the requirements for the output? the rest of the list is not sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Edited it. Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to achieve. Instead of the way you wrote it, here is a simpler approach:

```
import re
ls=set(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)) #text is the input
print(sorted(ls))
```

Tested it to make sure it works:
[image: Sample python program for set and sort]

**EDIT:**

I modified your code a bit to satisfy your use case.

```
fh = open(raw_input("Enter file name: "),'r')
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    words = line[:-1].split(" ")
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)
print(sorted(lst))
```

Output:

```
Enter file name: file.txt
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grie', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But my teacher especially asked for this method.

Comment: @RifatAbdurRahman I added an alternate code by modifying yours, check it out.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

line.split() gives you a list which will be added to your lst list as a list object. Therefore rather than using lst.append(line) use lst.extend(line) for the correct output.

Comment: Sorry. It did not work. I do not want to repeat repetitive words. For example: If i have 3 'lives' in the file, I want the output to show only one 'lives'.

Comment: then use  x = set(lst) at the final step to output the desired criteria.

Comment: you may use set operation to remove duplicates in your list.

Comment: Edited my post. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = []
with open('file_name') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        for j in words_to_split:
            i = ''.join(i.split(j))
        output.append(i)
```